# Linq to SQL and ASP.NET MVC 3 Integration

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3, orm, c#-4.0

How tightly can the ORM data classes generated by LINQ to SQL be integrated with the Model layer in MVC? Could these ORM data classes act directly as the model, if so, how would validation occur as it is usually done in MVC 3 with DataAnnotations? It seems that it would be diffiult to add these to the generated classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separation of Concerns suggests that the classes that make up your domain model *shouldn't* be dependant on the technology that's used to implement your Data Access Layer, so I make every effort to ensure that they're not propogated through the UI.

If you use Entity Framework instead of Linq-to-SQL, you can use the POCO generator instead of EF's default EntityObjects. While these are still generated from the EF database model, you can replace the data access implementation but retain the POCO's for your domain model.

Comment: it means we will have three type of model classes: 1-db-model classes, POCO objects acting as domain model and then comes viewmodels.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The DB model classes are DB implementation-specific. The ViewModels are UI implementation-specific. The domain model is the logical model that ties everything together. That's not unusual. Of course, both the DAL and the UI can use the domain model directly, if it's appropriate for their implementation, but the domain model should not be 'contaminated' with DAL or UI implementation detail (which makes some of the model attributes that we commonly use, questionable).

Comment: while i agree to this point, wouldn't it make it an overkill not only for small projects but for large projects as well because everytime you need a new object you have to create a triplet

Comment: It's a common trade-off. Invest a little effort up-front, or pay for it many times over during maintenance? Sticking with EF, remember that it will generate the POCO's for free and use them to implement the DAL, so in reality, there's little overhead unless you need to change the way things work, but at least you'll be able to with little effort. The argument that 'proper separation of concerns' is overkill will run and run, but I've seen the consequences of cutting corners many a time. It's a judgement call, at the end of the day.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, Muhammad. Especially for small projects.

Comment: I guess that rails then does not really adhere to as stricts an implementation of MVC as MVC 3 does.

Comment: @Jason i believe small projects are ideal scenarios to implement ideal architecture and in reality you can never tell when they grow to a monster. and its not technology that is adhering to anything its developer. you can very much use Ef entities in views no one is gonna stop you but they will advise you against it